# Sql / Java Query broken - cannot work with input from a dropdown?

Tags: java, sql

[image]

```
String sql = "SELECT ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME, ITEM_PRICE FROM HBDB.ITEMS WHERE 'ITEM_NAME' = "+burger.getSelectedItem()+""
```

Hello, I am using a `Java Database`, in `netbeans`, and am having trouble with my `sql` query. I'm not sure why this isn't working, however it is supposed to link to a drop down to query the database based on user input.

The result of my action ends with the output of a error message saying that 'CHEESEBURGER' is not a column in any of the given tables.

```
private void Order_Items () { 
       // String Burger = (String) burger.getSelectedItem();

    try{
        String sql = "SELECT ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME, ITEM_PRICE FROM HBDB.ITEMS WHERE 'ITEM_NAME' = '"+burger.getSelectedItem()+"'";
        //Defines What Data To Gain From Database
        mystate = myCon.createStatement(); 
        //Creates Statement and Connection
        myres = mystate.executeQuery(sql); 
        //Runs the Query 
        // Flag 
        // total_cost.setText(sql);
        // total_cost.setText(sql);  
        String id = Integer.toString(myres.getInt("ITEM_ID"));
        String name = myres.getString("ITEM_NAME");
        //Sets the Table Data as Strings for printing to total_cost
        String price = Double.toString(myres.getDouble("ITEM_PRICE"));
        total_cost.setText(id+","+name+","+price);
        // total_cost.setText(myres.);
    }  catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , e);
        // Catches Program Errors && Provides a Error Message 
        this.setVisible(false);
        // Closes the Screen If An Error Is Found
    }
}
```

This is the subprogram it's running in and the `try` does not work.

Comment: Hi Luke!  What do your tables actually look like?  I bet it isn't a column.

Comment: Yes it isnt? but it is data in the table? and I am not sure how to rectify this and make the query search for it as dat not a column

Comment: ill edit the question and insert a screenshot of the table

Comment: It would be better if you could insert actual text output of the table, so we can easily reproduce it, rather than a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your query 
just add ' before and after burger.getSelectedItem()
so it could be like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME, ITEM_PRICE FROM HBDB.ITEMS WHERE ITEM_NAME = '"+burger.getSelectedItem()+"'"
```

Also you should move your cursor

```
if(myres.next()){
//add your code to get data from the cursor
}
```

Comment: I tried this and then the error message changed to :Invalid Operation at cursor position

Comment: yes this is because you should use any method to move the cursor before getting data from it

Answer (score 0):

Why ITEM_NAME surround with "'" ？Don't surround field names with "''.
You'd better execute your sql in database before add it into code to make sure your sql is right.

Answer (score 0):

you should move your cursor before getting data

```
  if(myres.next()){
    //add your code to get data from the cursor
    String id = Integer.toString(myres.getInt("ITEM_ID"));
    //rest of your code
  }
```

Comment: do i need the loop if im only getting one result ?

Comment: no loops just an **if condition** to call the **next()** method and move the cursor one step. you can also use **first()**